# angular fails injecting factory into controller

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to inject factory in my controller.

```
var app = angular.module('BlogApp', ['ngMaterial']);

app.factory("Post", function ($resource) {
    return $resource("/rest/admin/search/posts");
});

app.controller('postController', ['$scope', function ($scope, Post) {
    $scope.getPost = Post.get({id: 1}, function (data) {
        //do something
    });
}
]);
```

Always get the same error that Post is undefined and **"Cannot read property 'get' of undefined"** What am i doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: To avoid this problem in future consider using something like gulp-ng-annotate (or whatever equivalent applies in your environment) to add the annotations automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed a parameter needed when minifying angularjs code :

```
app.controller('postController', ['$scope', function ($scope, Post) {
    $scope.getPost = Post.get({id: 1}, function (data) {
        //do something
    });
}
```

becomes :

```
app.controller('postController', ['$scope', 'Post', function ($scope, Post) {
    $scope.getPost = Post.get({id: 1}, function (data) {
        //do something
    });
}
```

Comment: seems like it helped but now i get following exception: Error: $injector:unpr
Unknown Provider
Unknown provider: $resourceProvider <- $resource <- Post

Comment: You forgot to include ngResource module/dependency (after ngMaterial)

Answer (score 2):

You don't list `Post` in your list of dependencies. Simply add it:

```
app.controller('postController', ['$scope', 'Post', function ($scope, Post) { /* ... */ }]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Inject your **ngResource** dependency into your module:

```
var app = angular.module('BlogApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngResource']);
```

And inject **Post** factory into your **controller**:

```
app.controller('postController', ['$scope', 'Post' function ($scope, Post) {

    $scope.getPost = Post.get({id: 1}, function (data) {
        //do something
    });

}]);
```

Hope it helps.